# Is it possible to invoke my java function after any insert / update / delete operations perfomed in any table in my postgres schema

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.4

Is it possible to invoke my Java function after any insert / update / delete operations performed in any table in my postgres schema? I have an application there I can do CRUD operations. Meanwhile, in another tab I have to display what are the tables are modified along with its value. Assume the both are entirely different projects.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve the same? Doesnt sound impossible

Comment: Just now i thought of doing this, Searched some oracle docs, and i can't find any..